# How to create interpolated string for termcolor.colored?

Tags: python, colors

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293633/14362977) answer for printing colored in python, but for printing variable I have problem because it prints it like a tuple like below:

```
from termcolor import colored
val = 'fruit'
print(colored(('Banana is', val), 'yellow'))
>>> ('Banana is', 'fruit')
```

But this is the output I want:

```
>>> Banana is fruit
```

(also without apostrophe)

Comment: The first argument of `colored` should be a string and you're passing in a tuple.

Comment: @np8 I pass it as tuple to show my problem.

Comment: If you print a tuple you will show a tuple in the terminal. If you print a string you'll see a string in the terminal. Right?

Comment: np8 Right. But `print(type(colored(('Banana is', val), 'yellow')))` is `<class 'str'>`. I have not printed tuple.

Comment: The problem statement here is "how to do string interpolation" (loosely said: "How to add two strings"). There is nothing related to termcolor or coloring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `f` behind the string makes it so u can insert variables into a string

```py
print(colored(f"Banana is {val}", 'yellow'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(colored(f"Banana is {val}", 'yellow'))
```